# Get data belongs to a field of model in select_related to a list and create a dataframe

Tags: django, pandas, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to query two related tables and create a pandas dataframe then use it for rule mining. The dataframe should look like this,

```
order   products
----------------
1       ['product1', 'product2']
2       ['product1', 'product3', 'product10']
...
```

My models,

```
class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderedProduct', related_name='orders')
    

class OrderedProduct(models.Model):

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Product(models.Model):
      
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

---

I've done the dataframe creating part as follows in views, and it works but needs preprocessing to get end result and feels it's inefficient for a larger dataset.

```
orders = OrderedProduct.objects.all().values('order__id', 'product__name')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(orders)
df = df.groupby(['order__id'])['product__name'].apply(list).to_list()
```

So, my question is '**Is there a more direct and efficient approach to do this?**'. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why you do not groupby in the first place, instead of fetching all of dataset?

Comment: You mean like this `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(orders).groupby(....)` ?

Comment: No, at the model layer.

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to this, i guess it has a better performanc:

```
OrderedProduct.objects.raw('SELECT order__id, GROUP_CONCAT(product__name) FROM myapp_OrderedProduct GROUP BY order__id')
```